# ImportError: No module named site [PYTHON] -- Error message appeared after working with Python for a while

Tags: python, environment-variables, importerror

Currently when I run a Python code (in Sublime Text 3) or try to run python in the cmd, I always get this:

```
C:\Users\Leopo\Flask App>python
ImportError: No module named site
```

In my user variables under the environment variables in PATH it is written: `C:\Users\Leopo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\` and `C:\Users\Leopo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\`

And in the system variables under PATH it is written:

```
%PYTHON_HOME%
```

with PYTHON_HOME : `C:\Users\Leopo\App Data\Local\Programms\Python38`

I already repaired and reinstalled Python 3.8.3.
Is there maybe a problem regarding the environment settings?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This problem has occurred to almost everyone
In my case, my system needed a restart to fix the problem